# convert object in to array of json with given keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I have object like

```
{ labels: ["city A", "city B"], data: ["Abc", "Bcd"] };
```

I want to convert above object as below array of json

```
[
  { labels: "city A", data: "Abc" },
  { labels: "city B", data: "Bcd" },
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with something like this:

```js
const original = {
  labels: ['city A', 'city B'],
  data: ['Abc', 'Bcd']
};

const merged = [];
const keys = Object.keys(original);
for (let idx = 0; idx < keys.length; idx++) {
  const entry = Object.assign.apply({},
    keys.map((key) => ({
      [key]: original[key][idx]
    }))
  );
  merged.push(entry);
}

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: How does this generate the desired output? There aren't even two input objects.

Comment: want to merge as [ { "labels":"city A", "data:"Abc"

},

{ "labels":"city B", "data:"Bcd"

}

]

Comment: Why is `original` an array of objects that has only 1 item?

Comment: @HarunYilmaz That's what the question was.

Comment: @Joel it seems that the question is converting an object to an array, but not an array to an array.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz Not sure I follow what you mean. Do you mean 'not an array of objects', but rather a plain object to an array of objects?

Comment: @Joel your code works fine. You just need to set `original = {...}` instead of `original = [{...}]` to make it an object instead of an array with 1 item.